# choose colour when plotting multivariate time series with ggfortify as overlay

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, statistics, ggfortify

```
library(ggfortify)
```

With ggfortify, if I plot one time series, I can set the line colour as follows:

```
autoplot(myts1,ts.colour='blue')
```

I can plot two ts objects in one graph:

```
autoplot(cbind(myts1,myts2),facets=FALSE)
```

But how can I set for example the line colour for the first ts 'blue' and for the second 'red'? In the second example, ts.colour doesn't work at all.

edit: here is a working example

```
myts1 = filter(rnorm(100), filter=rep(1,20),circular=TRUE)
myts2 = sin(seq(0,20,length.out=100))*5+5
autoplot(cbind(myts1,myts2),facets=FALSE)
```

Comment: can you include in your post a subset of your dataset, enough to reproduce the error?

Comment: and instead of cbind (your datasets) maybe your should merge them by the date. In the ggfortify manual, there is a example with 4 timeseries.

Comment: To elaborate on [Mlavoie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3396821/mlavoie)’s point about _ reproducing the error_. If you supply a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question we can use that to show you how it might be possible to answer your question––it's more likely that we will be able to help you.  You can have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a great reproducible example in R.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. I added a working example, but also already got the solution for my problem by the user sinhrks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scale_colour_manual`

When facet is disabled, `autoplot` colorize each series with "variable". Thus simply add `scale_colour_manual`.

```
pallete = c('red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange')
autoplot(Canada, facets = FALSE, size = 3) + scale_colour_manual(values=pallete)
```

[image]

Otherwise, you must specify `colour = "variable"` explicitly to colorize each series.

```
autoplot(Canada, size = 3, ts.colour = 'variable') + scale_colour_manual(values=pallete)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly the thing I was looking for.